# How to select batch rows by clicking shift key down in element-ui table?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I want to implement batch selection by clicking shift key. My solution is to implement keydown and keyup listening event. Set a var to determine whether shift key is down. And then loop the data to make the batch selection.

But I met the problems
1. I cannot get the right value of isShift, why?
2. If some column is sortable, it will be a problem to get the data after sorting.

https://codesandbox.io/s/editable-table-idea-g1pil

Any suggestion? Great thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change code. In method `creaed` event `onKeydown` you using anonymous function so `this.isShift` out of Vue data

```
created() {
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
      var key = window.event.keyCode;
      if (key === 16) {
        this.isShift = true;
      }
    };
    document.onkeyup = function(e) {
      this.isShift = false;
    };
  },
```

It should be

```
created() {
    document.onkeydown = this.onKeyDown;
    document.onkeyup =this.onKeyUp;
  },
methods: {
    onKeyDown() {
      var key = window.event.keyCode;
      if (key === 16) {
        this.isShift = true;
      }
    },
    onKeyUp() {
       this.isShift = false;
    },
}
```

Sorry if my English is bad

Comment: great thx @Davis !  I updated code https://codesandbox.io/s/editable-table-idea-g1pil. But I find another problem. When I click the checkbox directly, it will call handleCurrentChange twice. And the checkbox cannot be checked. Why? how to solve it. And do you have any suggestion for batch selection after sorting?

Comment: This issue is from `el-checkbox`. You can try to 

`<input type="checkbox" :checked="scope.row.checked" />`